# Transforming .mm file to readably form by java

Tags: java, c++, xml, json, transformation

I am developing Multi-mode resource-constrain project scheduling solver in Java. I was looking for test instances but only I found [this](http://www.om-db.wi.tum.de/psplib/datamm.html). It is in .mm file that is extension for C++ compilator. Is there any way how to transform this data into something easy readable by java like XML, JSON?

Comment: The .mm files look pretty straight forward to parse in your preferred language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested you could of course parse the file as a text file. Alternatively the two other main approaches would be:

- Use clang/llvm's [active syntax tree](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html) (AST) to interpret the data in the file.
- Use an Objective-C++ grammar for a compiler generator like [yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) or, since you're using Java, [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/). This will also yield a syntax tree, that you can that walk and extract information from.

Comment: Another solution in Java is to used parboiled